# Command Prompt read system output

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Hi Stackoverflow Community,

After many occasions of fixing computers using maintenance and integrity commands via command prompt manually I've decide I wanted to create a batch file doing the same techniques based upon command output. In terms of writing the batch file the only issue I'm struggling with it reading in data from command itself rather than text file. For example;

If Chkdsk comes back saying there multiple bad sectors, using if clause or another syntax it will schedule a repair i.e chkdsk /r next restart etc etc. The picture below with red highlighted are sections in which I wanted to read in if possible.

[image]

@echo off
chkdsk
/* If an issue been has found */
chkdsk /f

Comment: Check out the command `for` with its `/F` option, which provides the capability of reading and parsing the output of other commands; open a command prompt window and type `for /?` for details... I could imagine something like `chkdsk | find "in bad sectors"` and parse that like `for /F %%B in ('chkdsk ^| find "in bad sectors"') do (echo %%B)` (this just outputs the number of KB in bad sectors; to test that in command prompt directly rather than a batch file, state `%B` instead of `%%B` twice)...

Comment: @aschipfl As an academic side note, one might also check the SMART status of a hard drive with WMI.  For example: `wmic diskdrive where "not status='OK'" get caption,status /value` would give you a list of drives whose SMART status is in a warning / error state.  `wmic /namespace:\\root\wmi path MSStorageDriver_FailurePredictData` would return byte arrays containing more detailed status info, although I haven't conceived of a way to decipher those values.  I suspect that [this article](http://www.i-programmer.info/projects/38-windows/208-disk-drive-dangers.html?start=1) might hold the primer.

Comment: Great idea, @rojo! Does such a WMI query trigger a disk check, or does it rely on a preceding one?

Comment: @aschipfl It contains a count of read failures, hdd temperature, known bad clusters, and so on.  It doesn't trigger an active scan, as it's more a hardware thing than a filesystem thing.  Not all falling hard drives fail SMART thresholds before their true death; but if a hard drive shows a status of "PredFail", It's time to back up your data and replace it.  SMART is a complement to chkdsk, not a replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you want to search for two strings, you either have to do an unsane amount of code or just parse the output twice. Use a temporary file for that to not have to run the `chkdsk` command twice:

```
chkdsk d: >out.txt
type out.txt
find "No further action is required" out.txt >nul && find " 0 KB in bad sectors" out.txt >nul && goto :good
REM repair
:good
echo nothing to do
```